# How to define a javascript function with a name equal to a string

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

Let's say I'm given a string, and I want to define a function with a name of that string. How can I do this?

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that I do not want to set an anonymous function to a property because I would also like to dynamically grab the function's name from inside the function ie. `arguments.callee.name`

Comment: If you've already been given the name, why do you need to then obtain that name again from `arguments.callee.name`?

Comment: @JamesAllardice because I'm dynamically rewriting the `removeChild` javascript method of `Element`'s prototype

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. Some code in your question might help. But as a side note, don't forget that `arguments.callee` is deprecated, and throws a syntax error in strict mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var functionName = "myfunction"
window[functionName] = function() {
    // your function here
}
```

Depending on the requirements, maybe something like this would work:

```
var myFunctionGenerator = function(name) {return function(message) {
    alert("hi, this is a function named '" + name + "'.  The parameter passed is '" + message + "'.");
}}

var myFunction = myFunctionGenerator('some function name');
myFunction('a parameter');
// hi, this is a function named 'some function name'.  The parameter passed is 'a parameter'.
```

Comment: ah, I forget to mention that I do not want to set an anonymous function to a property because I would also like to dynamically grab the function's name from inside the function ie. `arguments.callee.name`

Comment: @user730569 Just remember that `callee` and strict mode... not so good.

Comment: @DaveNewton is there an alternative?

Comment: @user730569 - The alternative is usually to use a named function expression. But without more information about what you're actually trying to achieve, I think it's going to be difficult to help properly.

Comment: @DaveNewton dbaseman's second solution works like a charm... and it doesn't use `callee`, so it's a win-win :)

Comment: @user730569 Well, the function isn't named `some function name`, it's named `myFunction`--glad it works, but it's a different thing.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, i guess I didn't correctly phrase what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If your declaring the function, use `eval()`. Just type a string representation of the argument your trying to execute for example:

```
eval("function name(){alert('a');}");
```

You can then call that method by normal convention, `name();`.

If you already have the function name and want to call that function with a string representation you can use the `eval()` method, although its not always optimal for performance. You will have this:

```
var fnName = "functionName";
var params = "param1";
var fnNameWithParams = "functionName("+params+")";
eval(fnNameWithParams);
```

A better approach may be:

```
var fnName = "functionName";
var params = "param1";
var fnToCall = window[fnName];
fnToCall(params);
```

Comment: "its not always optimal for performance"... it's not optimal for almost anything. Unfortunately, I don't know if there's going to be any way the OP can achieve what they are trying to without it (at least not without more information).